# How to pass ObjectID as query parameter in node-red to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-red

I am using [node-red-contrib-mongodb3](https://github.com/ozomer/node-red-contrib-mongodb2) and having trouble to pass an ObjectId as an argument, not being able to use a MongoDB auto-generated _id, is there any way to use "_id": 'ObjectId("myID")' as an argument?

I have followed the module tutorial on passing query parameters [node-red-contrib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-mongodb3#usage)

**Here is an example:**

I have the following document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9156c7f8c3ec3259454571"),
    "name" : "teste_site_1",
}
```

If I pass as msg.payload to findOne Operation

```
msg.payload = { "name" : "teste_site_1" }
```

returns my document without ObjectID in _id

```
{
    "_id" : "5c9156c7f8c3ec3259454571",
    "name" : "teste_site_1",
}
```

if I pass the _id as argument:

```
msg.payload = { "_id" : "5c9156c7f8c3ec3259454571" }
```

returns empty.

I can not call ObjectId in node-red and also cannot pass as string ObjectId.

I wonder if there is already a way to pass ObjectId as an argument.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved by using as a parameter the return of ObjectId function in 'mongodb' node module but in order to use node modules inside a function node, one must import it to global context inside your node-red directory.
on windows:

```
C:\\users\username\.node-red\settings.js
```

in Ubuntu

```
~\.node-red\settings.js
```

and include the ObjectId as global import

```
functionGlobalContext: {
        require: require, // Not mandatory
        ObjectId : require('mongodb').ObjectID,
},
```

I have also included 'require' module for some may find it useful to not mess with settings.js and also make it unnecessary the process restart to add future modules.

And inside the function node, I just passed the payload as follows.

```
var ObjectId = global.get('ObjectId');

msg.payload={
    "_id":ObjectId("5c9156c7f8c3ec3259454571")
};

return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, another alternative

Linux File Path

```
.../?/.node-red/settings.js
```

JS Code

```
functionGlobalContext: {
    require:require,
    ObjectId:require('mongodb-core').BSON.ObjectID
    // os:require('os'),
},
```

or

```
functionGlobalContext: {
    ObjectId:require('mongodb-core').BSON.ObjectID
    // os:require('os'),
},
```

Node-RED Function node

```
const ObjectId = this.context.global.get('ObjectId');
msg.payload = { "_id": ObjectId("6389dd5bd708890ea34d0d8a")};
return msg;
```